# How I show a new form when my timer stops

Tags: c#, forms, timer, controls, clock

At my solution i've 2 forms (form1 form2), and form1 checks automatically if user exist and if exist, these same form call the form2 and when form2 appear form1 hide.

Happens that in form1 i have an timer called "clock" that allow me control time and when 15 seconds occours can call the form2 or show throught an label that user does not exist.

At start my solution open 2 forms at same time, but i want that clock running the 15 seconds and when clock.stop() method occours, solution should be present form2 and hide form1.

Code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            clock.Start();
            //Checkuser
            label8.Show();
            editus uti = new editus();
            Form2 formdois = new Form2();
            uti.getxmlfile();
            uti.check_node(formdois);
            clock.Stop();

        }
```

How I can do this?

Note: Do you understand my problem? (i'm portuguese and my english is a little bad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a timer that waits for 15 seconds and then fires OnTimerTicked method.

Inside OnTimerTicked load the second form:

```
  Timer t = new Timer();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = 15000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTicked);
        t.Start();
    }

    public void OnTimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
        Form2 formdois = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
```